# java webservice generated proxy problem in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy

I create the webservice from netbean as java webservice. when i Applying the web reference to my asp.net web application. it generate proxy . but i found that the methods also convert in classes.Also i found the method as methods in class that i define in web service...I have web method that have the return type int (in java). but in proxy i found its return type as void. why these issue ??

Comment: It would be nice if you posted wsdl file here, to dig into the problem

Comment: We definately need the wsdl to diagnose further

Answer (score 0):

You would have to refine your question a bit in order to get some answers. Answering to the following questions might help us provide an answer:
1. What version of Visual Studio and .Net Framework are you using?
2. Are you using WCF (adding the service with "Add service reference") or WSE (adding the service with "Add web reference")?
3. Can you please post the WSDL?
4. The fact that a int return type is translated into void in the client is the only problem that you are facing?

Regards,
Florin